# Using Raven, how to save exception to file and sent later to Sentry?

Tags: python, sentry, raven

In my Python app, I have been working with Raven+Sentry to catch exception and sent it to sentry at the time of the exception occur, code below:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
from raven import Client

client = Client(dsn='<MY SENTRY DSN>')
try:
    MyApp().run()
except:
    import traceback
    traceback.print_exc()
    ident = client.get_ident(client.captureException())
    print "Exception caught; reference is %s" % ident
```

It will sent the exception directly to Senty backend just after the application crashed. What I want to accomplished is, saving the exception first to local file and then send it later on when the app starting.

Do Sentry+Raven support this kind of functionality?